# MPI synchronize matrix of vectors

Tags: c++, vector, matrix, synchronization, mpi

Excuse me if this question is common or trivial, I am not very familiar with MPI so bear with me.

I have a matrix of vectors. Each vector is empty or has a few items in it.

```
std::vector<someStruct*>  partitions[matrix_size][matrix_size];
```

When I start the program each process will have the same data in this matrix, but as the code progresses each process might remove several items from some vectors and put them in other vectors.

So when I reach a barrier I somehow have to make sure each process has the latest version of this matrix. The big problem is that each process might manipulate any or all vectors.

How would I go about to make sure that every process has the correct updated matrix after the barrier?

EDIT:
I am sorry I was not clear. Each process may move one or more objects to another vector but only one process may move each object. In other words each process has a list of objects it may move, but the matrix may be altered by everyone. And two processes can't move the same object ever.

Comment: If each processor manipulates potentially any element, how the heck do you decide what the "correct updated matrix" is?

Comment: I am sorry I was not clear. Each process may move one or more objects to another vector but only one process may move each object.

Answer (score 1):

In that case you'll need to send messages using `MPI_Bcast` that inform the other processors about this and instruct them to do the same. Alternatively, if the ordering doesn't matter until you hit the barrier, you can only send the messages to the root process which performs the permutations and then after the barrier sends it to all the others using `MPI_Bcast`.

One more thing: vectors of pointers are usually quite a bad idea, as you'll need to manage the memory manually in there. If you can use C++11, use `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` instead (depending on what your semantics are), or use Boost which provides very similar facilities.

And lastly, representing a matrix as a fixed-size array of fixed-size arrays is readlly bad. First: the matrix size is fixed. Second: adjacent rows are not necessarily stored in contiguous memory, slowing your program down like crazy (it literally can be orders of magnitudes). Instead represent the matrix as a linear array of size `Nrows*Ncols`, and then index the elements as `Nrows*i + j` where `Nrows` is the number of rows and `i` and `j` are the row and column indices, respectively. If you don't want column-major storage instead, address the elements by `i + Ncols*j`. You can wrap this index-juggling in inline functions that have virtually zero overhead.

Comment: Thank You, i'm not sure about how to send these instructions only to the root, but I can probably figure that out. As for the matrix part I don't really need the speed at the moment, but I agree that it would be a better solution. I will try this out!

Comment: You really should take a look at the [MPI documentation](http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/docs.html) then. It's really quite readable and contains a lot of examples.

Comment: In C, elements in static 2D arrays are stored contiguously (line-by-line, defined in 8.3.4). So if you access them appropriately, they are not a performance problem.  (There are other issues though.)

Comment: `MPI_Broadcast` is not the right tool if everyone wants to share information that everyone else needs to know (at the same time) --> `MPI_Allgather`

Comment: @Zulan that's only true if all of them have to share it at the same time. And you're right, if the arrays are static. However, as soon as the "rows" are dynamically allocated, you're out of luck.

Comment: You are not out of luck as long as there are user-defined datatypes in MPI and `MPI_Allgatherv`.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to lay out the data differently:

Each process has a map of his objects and their position in the matrix. How that is implemented depends on how you identify objects. If all local objects are numbered, you could just use a `vector<pair<int,int>>`.

Treat that as the primary structure you manipulate and communicate that structure with `MPI_Allgather` (each process sends it data to all other processes, at the end everyone has all data). If you need fast lookup by coordinates, then you can build up a cache.

That may or may not be performing well. Other optimizations (like sharing 'transactions') totally depend on your objects and the operations you perform on them.